# Cannot add GitHub API header "Authorization token" to GET request in Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, github-api

GitHub APi documentation says that I need to pass **access token** in **header**.
[image]

This command works fine for me with replacing OAUTH_TOKEN to mine. I try to do the same in code:

```
    @GET("/user/repos")
    fun getAllUserRepos(
        @Header("Authorization: token") accessToken: String
    ): Call<List<RepoJson>>
```

But when I get error in **enqueque onFailure**: Unexpected char 0x20 at 14 in header name: Authorization: token. Then I remove space remove space between *Authorization:* and *token* in **header** and get **Unauthorized** message from responce in **onResponce**.

I tried this (also with space between *Authorization:* and *token* in **header**):

```
    @Headers("Authorization: token MY_VALID_TOKEN")
    @GET("/user/repos")
    fun getAllUserRepos(): Call<List<RepoJson>>
```

And it executed successfully (through enqueue).

My API:

```
val api: GiHubApi = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(GitHubApi::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per doc,
key="Authorization" and value="token VALID_TOKEN"

In the Retrofit,
you need to pass the key to `@GET`. But you're passing "Authorization: token"

So you need to do it like this.

```
@GET("/user/repos")
    fun getAllUserRepos(
        @Header("Authorization") accessToken: String
    ): Call<List<RepoJson>>
```

Call

```
getAllUserRepos("token $VALID_TOKEN")
```

Comment: This answer is misleading, because there is no string `token` involved.

Answer (score 2):

The header should be:

```
@GET("/user/repos")
fun getAllUserRepos(
    @Header("Authorization") accessToken: String
): Call<List<RepoJson>>
```

Been there, done [that](https://github.com/syslogic/androidx-github/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/io/syslogic/github/retrofit/GithubService.java).